# How to Select all checkbox and get list of selected rows in data grid view in c# win form?

Tags: c#

Hi ever stack overflow users.
my question is similar to all of other user's questions but I have another problem with that.
My Problem :
I have a project in win form c# vs 2022.I have data grid view in c# win form and user can select all rows checkbox or row by row.
I have made a column in data grid view designer named it "Select" and put 0 to false value and 1 to true value in it.
Now when I press check all button all rows select and it's fine but when I after that select single rows it gets error on casting string to Boolean.
please help me how to solve this kind of error.

my code:

```
    private void btnSelectALl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            if (DG_Joint.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DG_Joint.Rows)
                {
                    DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chk = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)row.Cells[0];
                    chk.Value = !(chk.Value == null ? false : (bool)chk.Value);
                }
            }
    }
```

and :

```
                    List<int> JointList = new();

                //check for selected check box in DG_Joint
                foreach (DataGridViewRow? row in DG_Joint.Rows)
                {
                    if (row.Cells[0].GetType() == typeof(DataGridViewCheckBoxCell))
                    {
                        DataGridViewCheckBoxCell? chk = row.Cells[0] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;

                        if (chk.Value is not null)
                        {

                            if (chk.Value.ToString() == "True" || chk.Value.ToString() == "1")
                            {
                                int.TryParse(row.Cells["JointID"].Value.ToString(), out int jointId);

                                JointList.Add(jointId);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }//end foreach
```

I know where is my problem but I don't know how to solve it.
when I click with selectAll button it put all data grid view checkbox cell value to Boolean but  when I click row by row it return 0,1 string value of TrueValue and FalseValue of deata grid view.

Comment: There is no need to convert a Boolean to string in order to check the value.  Use the awesome debugger to refine your code to drop that odious step.

Answer (score 1):

When selecting all rows, set the boolean value directly to `true` or `false` rather than relying on integer representations (0 or 1).
When checking individual rows, interpret the checkbox value as a boolean directly without comparing it to string representations.

```
 private void btnSelectAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
  if (DG_Joint.Rows.Count > 0)
   {
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DG_Joint.Rows)
    {
        DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chk = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)row.Cells[0];
        chk.Value = !(chk.Value == null ? false : (bool)chk.Value);
      }
   }
 }


 // Code to retrieve selected rows
 List<int> JointList = new List<int>();

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DG_Joint.Rows)
 {
  if (row.Cells["Select"] is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chk && chk.Value is bool isChecked && isChecked)
  {
    int.TryParse(row.Cells["JointID"].Value.ToString(), out int jointId);
    JointList.Add(jointId);
  }
}
```

the checkbox values are consistently treated as boolean values rather than comparing them to string representations of `True` or `False`.

Comment: tnx man. but your code just select all and when click to revert it it doesn't work because you set it to chk.Value = true; // Set to true for selection

Comment: I edited please check it now

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solve that Error for casting with thsi code:

```
    public static void SelectAllRows(DataGridView dgv)
    {
        if (dgv.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
            {
                DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chk = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)row.Cells[0];

                if (chk.Value == null)
                    chk.Value = !false;
                else if(chk.Value.GetType() == typeof(bool))
                    chk.Value = !(bool)chk.Value;
                else if (chk.Value.GetType() == typeof(String))
                {
                    if(chk.Value.ToString() == "1")
                        chk.Value = !true;
                    else
                        chk.Value = !false;  
                }

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**